# gatsby --version > -bash: gatsby: command not found

Tags: npm, gatsby

I use mac and I installed gatsby-cli by:

```
npm install --global gatsby-cli
```

and 'npm root -g' command prints:

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/node_modules
```

npm successfully installed gatsby but,
I cannot run gatsby command (gatsby --version, gatsby --help)
Whenever I type and run "gatsby --version" it prints:

```
-bash: gatsby: command not found
```

Is there any way I can fix this problem??

Comment: could you please try `gatsby info` instead of checking `version` ?

Comment: gatsby info >>>>
-bash: gatsby: command not found

Comment: have you reopened the terminal ?

Comment: I use bash terminal. I don't understand what you are meaning by "responded the terminal"

Comment: i mean close your bash terminal and open terminal then run the command and check

Comment: I closed and opened again.. it returns the same message.. -bash: gatsby: command not found

Comment: check my updated ans

Comment: Thankyou! it solved~ Now i can run gatsby --version

Comment: Take a look at [this post](https://datawookie.dev/blog/2023/04/installing-gatsby/) for a few different approaches to installing `gatsby-cli`.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

you have to update your config. You may have to follow few steps

Set Config

remove existing config

```
npm config delete prefix
```

set new config

```
npm config set prefix /usr/local
```

Install gatsby

```
npm i -g gatsby-cli
```

now check version

```
gatsby --version
```

Comment: I did it.. but it still returns >>>-bash: gatsby: command not found

Comment: oh! it helps!! now i can get result for gatsby --version
Thankyou a lot!!!

Comment: Nice. Can you elaborate what the issue is? Why does the solution work?

Comment: @XaverFleer npm config prefix might be pointing to incorrect location. so we are removing it and setting new location.

Comment: Great. It worked on my end, now set at 3.0 (I had installed gatsby locally before in the project folder) 
`Gatsby CLI version: 3.0.0
Gatsby version: 3.0.0`

Answer (score 5):

Instead of trying to install globally, you can use ***npx***

```
 npx gatsby new my_dir_name
```

Then run:

```
npx gatsby develop
```

Then:

```
npx gatsby build
```

And then you can run them using

```
npm run develop
npm run build
```

Comment: this seems like the cleanest solution IMO

Comment: This solution worked for me. For some unknown reason, I could not run then npm global command. You save my day. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same issue. `npx gatsby -v` worked. Hope this helps somebody.
Reference: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/15276#issuecomment-507340096

Comment: This doesn't actually mean it is installed locally. "npx" will just pull from the NPM global repository to grab it temporarily and then run the command with it, but it isn't installed locally which means anytime you want to do anything with gatsby you have to start it with "npx". https://github.com/npm/npx

Answer (score 2):

In my case i was missing sudo on install:

`sudo npm i -g gatsby-cli`